# TextView is not showing in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i've issue with the TextView in XML.
this is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".frontScreen">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/plan"
            android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
           />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plan1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plan2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />


</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

if i write TextView is linear layout. then it overlapped with buttons. so i use 2 layouts relative and linear.
when i click the TextView in design it looks like that TextView has exact space that i want but Text is disappeared

Comment: please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".frontScreen">




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plan1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plan2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="plan"
            android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

hope this helps. But for better working you need to take relativelayout and linearlayout in single layout. feel free to ask if this doesn't works

EDIT:

If you need this in a single view you can try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="plan"
            android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plan1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plan2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Excellent but can you elaborate. why TextView is not showing in my case?

Comment: I need to know reason behind this.!

Comment: In your case RelativeLayout is hidden below LinearLayout. So thats why when you put RelativeLayout below LinearLayout your relativelayout is gone up on LinearLayout. Hope you understand

Comment: For better view you need to take text view in single layout. you dont need relative and linear layout both. If this helps mark this as a correct answer so others getting help from this @MuhammadSaadBhatti

Comment: This thing collapse the button and textview. can you show the demo in single layout?

Comment: welcome @MuhammadSaadBhatti Happy to help you :) :) :)